# Setting AllowAutoRedirect=false still follows redirect

Tags: c#, .net, azure

i locally developed an MVC controller that performs a request to a URL and setting the ... everything is fine:

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
_WebRequest.Method = "GET";
_WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)_WebRequest.GetResponse()) {
string _response = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
[...]
```

When i test this locally everything is fine and i get the 302 redirect status code. 
I deployed that on Azure (MVC service) and the same code acts in a different way: basically it follows redirects and the status code 200 is retrieved.

Comment: I really don't think this is an issue with Azure as the setting to auto redirect is on the client and is agnostic of the server technology. I would start with Fiddler on my machine and see what request/response is being sent, then debug my service on Azure to ensure it is actually redirecting

Comment: i checked with Fiddler and locally everything is fine, but once deployed on Azure the behaviour is different: locally i receive the 302 status code, instead on cloud i receive the 200 status code; that's why i was wondering if that could be due to some "setting" on the IIS on Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I tested this issue both on my local side and Azure side. Here are the detailed content, you could refer to it and compare with your scenario.

**/Home/TestRedirect**: Perform a request to a URL which contains a 302 redirect.

```
public ActionResult TestRedirect(bool allowAutoRedirect=true)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://bruce-chen-002.azurewebsites.net/home/doredirect");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = allowAutoRedirect;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        string _response = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return Content(_response);
    }
}
```

**/Home/DoRedirect** Perform a 302 redirect.

```
public ActionResult DoRedirect()
{
    return Redirect("https://azure.microsoft.com");
}
```

**1.Test on local side**

`AllowAutoRedirect=true`

[image]

`AllowAutoRedirect=false`

[image]

**Note:** You could capture the server-side request, since the site is launched by your local IIS Server. To determine that whether the request is redirected, you could check the response of the original request you sent as above.

**2.Test on Azure Web App**

`AllowAutoRedirect=true`

[image]

`AllowAutoRedirect=false`

[image]

**Note:** In order to capture the redirect in Azure, you could leverage [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net), then you could retrieve it under "Overview > Search" blade of your Application Insights in Azure Portal as follows:

[image]

Comment: So is the value of `AllowAutoRedirect` doesn't matter? I'm not sure what we see here...When you tested locally, you got 302 then 200 regardless of `AllowAutoRedirect`'s value? And when you tested on Azure, you got just 200 - again regardless of `AllowAutoRedirect`'s value?